# Trying to remove links from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$.get("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afghanistan", function(response) {
  var elements = $.parseHTML(response);
  var wiki = $(elements).find('#mw-content-text').find("p");
  var ps = [];

  var arrayLength = wiki.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    if (wiki[i].innerHTML === "") {
      break;
    }
    var item = wiki[i]
    ps.push(item);
    $("#fakediv").append(ps);
}
```

I am trying to remove the links from the variable `item`, but I can't seem to find any examples of how to do this from a variable - everything assumes that I'll be using a selector.

I've tried .removeAttr("href"), but that doesn't seem to work and I'm not quite sure how to remove links and leave the text.

Comment: How does a `<p>` have a `href`?

Comment: So why don't you use a selector?

Comment: Could this be accomplished with a simple RegEx replace? If I'm understanding the question correctly, you could just replace `/(<a[^>]+>)([^<]+)(</a>)/gi with `$2` to remove the `a` tag surrounding the text in the string.

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to unlink the links, but you are looping over paragraph elements and trying to remove its attribute. I doubt the paragraph has an href attribute.

So you need to find the anchors inside the paragraph tags

```
var item = wiki.eq(i);
item.find("a").removeAttr("href")
ps.push(item);
```

or

```
var item = wiki.eq(i);
item.find("a").contents().unwrap();
ps.push(item);
```

Comment: item.find is not a function

Comment: This was almost right. One minor change and I will accept the answer:

$(item).find("a").contents().unwrap();

Comment: find should return a jQuery object, and eq() returns a jquery object. So not sure why it would not work since wrapping it in a $ should be equivalent.